# Split a string than join, for cast

Tags: sql, split, casting, firebird

I have a table with this column

```
DATEFROM VARCHAR(8)
```

It's a string in the format 'yyyyMMdd'. I need to convert this element to Date Type.

I thought to split the string in 3 substrings (yyyy, MM, dd), than join them by adding '-' between the strings. In this way, i can cast to Date type.

How can I do it?

Comment: Why is this a varchar at all and not a `DATE`? Also what did you try and search for? A minimum amount of own work to solve your problem is expected for questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Which database are you using firebird?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I have done my minimum amount of work before asking here.... I'm NOT the owner of this DB. However, i have reached my gol and i have updated the Question.

Comment: The minimum amount of work should be demonstrated in your question (eg by showing what you tried and explaining why it didn't work. However, if you managed to solve your problem, then please post it as an answer, not as an edit to your question. Self-answering questions is allowed and even encouraged.

Comment: Don't put answers in question posts, post an answer post. [help] [ask] [answer] Read the tag wiki before using a tag.

Answer (score 1):

Repeating the answer that was posted in the question so that it doesn't show up as a question without an answer:

```
select cast(substring(datadal 
   from 1 for 4)||'-'||substring(datadal from 5 for 2)||'-'||substring(datadal from 7 for 2) AS DATE) as datadal
```